# Dismissible Widget in ListView does not animate smoothly

Tags: listview, dart, widget, flutter, dismissible

I'm using a dismissible widget in a List view for swipe to delete. Here is my code for the dismissible Item:

```
new Dismissible(
        key: new Key(visitor.id.toString()),
        onDismissed: (direction) {
          Visitor removedVisitor;
          setMountedState(() {
            removedVisitor = _visitors.removeAt(index);
          });
          _deleteVisitor(removedVisitor, index);
        },
        // Show a red background as the item is swiped away
        background: new LeaveBehindView(),
        child: item,
      )
```

(setMountedState is a function which is basically => `if(mounted) setState...`)

The problem is, from the examples, the swipe action is supposed to animate the item below the dismissed item smoothly after resizing. But in my case, the animation is abrupt. I have tried changing the values of `resizeDuration` but the animation is still not smooth.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the _deleteVisitor is a function that calls an API. It takes far too long to wait for the API to respond and then update the list.

Comment: I just checked the docs and the callback passed to `setState()` actually is called immediately synchronous, so this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I've checked by removing the _deleteVisitor function altogether. The animation is still very abrupt. I'm not sure if it's because I'm using custom widgets as items in the ListView...

Comment: What do you mean with "custom widgets in the ListView"? Is the `Dismissable` not the direct child of `ListView`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer sorry, I meant custom widget as a child for `Dismissible` - the sample apps have ListTile as a child and not a custom widget.

Comment: I just wanted to be sure. I think that's ok. Should be easy enough to find out if using `ListTile` changes anything.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer no it didn't make a difference, just checked...